# test class for ConnectAPI in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce-chatter

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
//Mention user here
mentionSegmentInput.id = a.OwnerId;
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

textSegmentInput.text = ' Description field is empty ' + c[0].lastModifiedDate;
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = a.Id;

ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput);

ConnectApi.LinkCapabilityInput linkInput = new ConnectApi.LinkCapabilityInput();
linkInput.url = '/'+c[0].id;
linkInput.urlName = 'Doc link';
ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput feedElementCapabilitiesInput =
        new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
feedElementCapabilitiesInput.link = linkInput;
feedItemInput.capabilities = feedElementCapabilitiesInput;
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, feedItemInput);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in what exactly your question is?

Comment: I want to test that logic.